# Better search system for questions

Tags: discussion

A big disadvantage of askubuntu is his search system, I think.

It is pretty unlikely to find the right answer in the pool, even though it is there.

Even the *Questions that may already have your answer*     'search' if you asking a question is better...

Would it be so complicated to improve the search system?

Comment: What algorithm do you propose?

Comment: I never too a closer look at search algorithms, but often even  keywords are not found correctly. what would be about extracting keywords from a file (using pearl?) and save them in a XML metadata file to search after these keywords, this would at least display more results.

Comment: Can you provide us an example of a search you think gives bad results?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283475/792066

Comment: This issue exists across all SE sites. If you search meta.stackexchange.com you will find feature request similar to this.

Comment: Even as I was about to ask this question, "Questions that already have an answer" found this.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is complicated at the brainstorm stage.  Make a search function past what we already have using the same ideal, and complicated is no longer something people say.  Dev teams know what works is some thing simple yet elegant in design.  With every project I and some others have collaberate on use MySQL(or equivlant) no such thing is simple ever existed.  Irratiting and agravated are usually the moods after 3 days of full debugging and swear words in forms of paragraphs granted.  The String Search Engine does what we need it to without too much fuss.